# Newman loads the pfx certificate but it is not used to connect to the endpoint

Tags: ssl, certificate, postman, pfx, newman

I'm having issue in execute a postman collection, from newman, which involves loading a pfx certificate to establish a TLSMA connection.

From the Postman application, the certificate is loaded correctly (from the setting) and used for the domain https://domain1.com to connect with a TLSMA counterpart server.

When I export the json collection and environment there is no mention about domain and certificate associated.

Checking the json schema [here](https://schema.postman.com/collection/json/v2.1.0/draft-07/collection.json) newman accepts a certificate definition in the request but applying it does not work, here my example:

```
 "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "header": [],
    "certificate": {
      "name": "Dev or Test Server",
      "matches": ["https://domain1.com/*"],
      "cert": { "src": "./certificate.pfx" }
    },
    "url": {
      "raw": "https://domain1.com/as/authorization.oauth2",
      "host": ["https://domain1.com"],
      "path": ["as", "authorization.oauth2"],
      "query": [
        {
```

I also tried to apply the certificate configuration in an external file cert-list.json with the following content:

```
[{
    "name": "Dev or Test Server",
    "matches": ["https://domain1.com/*"],
    "cert": { "src": "./certificate-t.pfx" }
  }]
```

but it does not work either.

Here the newman command:

```
newman run domain.postman_collection.json -n 1 --ssl-client-cert-list cert-list.json  -e env.postman_environment.json -r cli --verbose
```

[image]

Do you know where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change cert to pfx
try:

```
[{
  "name": "Dev or Test Server",
  "matches": ["https://domain1.com/*"],
  "pfx": { "src": "./certificate-t.pfx" }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too by creating a separate json file with the path to the .pfx, then pass to newman. 
newman run 'collection.json' --environment 'my-env.json' --ssl-client-cert-list cert.json

Answer (score 0):

We are using  similar json to pass the pfx but it is not at all working for us getting error when collection is run using newman..

[errored]
unsupported

same collection runs perfectly fine with the .crt and .key file passed through the same json.